I have French nationality by decree and my ex husband has it by marriage. Do my adult children have right to citizenship?
My oldest son and I applied for and received French nationality, our other two children have British Nationality and carte de sejour.  I believe my ex-husband (the childrens' father) has taken French nationality by marriage to his second wife.
Would having both parents having French Nationality give the children the right to French nationality too? If so, how could I verify he has indeed taken French nationality.
He lives in France but cut off contact with the children several years ago.

How old are these children?  How old were they when you obtained French nationality?  Their father's having obtained it may be irrelevant.

In addition to @phoog's very important question, a few other details may matter: Where were your children born and how old were they when they entered France? Did they grow up in France (in practice: have they completed the French compulsory education)?

Youngest is now 24, he was 16 when I submitted family dossier, 18 by the time I got nationality decree. He, like his brother , who was  20 when he got his nationality has lived in France since they were 3 and 6 and received all their education here. Youngest has carte residence.

Sorry, I made a mistake and deleted my last comment. At this point, I don't see any procedure other than naturalisation.


Would having both parents having French Nationality give the children the right to French nationality too?

Not as such, probably because all the other rules (nationality by descent, effet collectif, right to become French for people born in France or for siblings of French citizen who grew up in the country) would make a situation like yours relatively rare. Since your children do not live with their father, his acquiring French citizenship after they were born is generally irrelevant. And to the extent that having French parents matter (e.g. citizenship by descent at birth, double ius soli) then having one French parent is enough, the citizenship of the other parent doesn't matter at all.
That said, there may be other routes for your children to become French depending on their age and how long they lived in France, either as a delayed effet collectif of your own déclaration, because they grew up in France and have a brother who is a French citizen, or if they were born and grew up in France.
If all else fails, it might be advisable to apply for a carte de résident as children of a French citizen (you). This would secure their right to live in France until they qualify for naturalisation on their own. Ideally you want to do that just before they turn 18, in any case before they turn 21, as it might be troublesome to maintain their current status or transition to another one as they become independent. Adult children of French citizens do not enjoy any special path to residence or citizenship in France.

Thank you for that information. When I made a family application for citizenship my youngest son was 16 and I was told he wouldn't need an individual application as , when I had my interview he was 16. However,  although his brother was awarded nationality at 19 based on the family application my youngest son was told he must re-submit , which he did a it was approved and was sent to the ministry .it turned out they had l misplaced his file.
